# This browser does not support WebGL. at createWebGLRenderingContextFromCanvas?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am learning **Tensorflow** using the **Tensorflow.js** library for machine learning when I run my simple program getting the following warning

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.5"> </script>

    <!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
    <script>
     tf.tensor([1,2,3,4,5]).print();
     tf.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).print();
     
    
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

> This browser does not support WebGL. at
> createWebGLRenderingContextFromCanvas

what's the exact root cause for this?

Comment: When you run the code snippet below using the latest version of Chrome, do you still have the same error ?

Comment: yes I am getting warning whenever i used latest version and I had also tried on firefox and IE  but still same result.

Comment: Is it a warning or an error ? The print does not show anything in the console ? In either way, you can fill an issue in GitHub for tfjs-core.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem in Chrome by enabling "Use hardware acceleration when available" in Chrome. So I go to "Setting", click on "Advanced", and then enable "Use hardware acceleration when available".

Comment: Please read [When should code formatting be used for non-code text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561)